# How do I update information in the database using POST in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm creating a contact list that lets the user Add, Delete, and Edit using Django.  I've been able to slowly work my way through most of it except for updating the information in the database after the user hits "Submit".

I've tried a few different methods that I thought might work, but unfortunately I just ended up with Errors.  So I'm wondering, after I render the html edit form and the user edits whatever field they choose and hits submit, how do I receive that information and update the database with it?  I've read that I need to use a 'POST' but I'm not sure how to set it up.

views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpRequest
from django.template import loader
from .models import Contact

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the contacts app.")

def list(request):
    contacts_list = Contact.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'contact_list':contacts_list})

def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_contact = Contact(
            firstname = request.POST['firstname'],
            lastname = request.POST['lastname'],
            age = request.POST['age'],
            phone = request.POST['phone'],
            email = request.POST['email'],
            gender = request.POST['gender'],
        )
        new_contact.save()
        return redirect('/contacts/list/')
    return render(request, 'addform.html')

def edit(request, cur_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        contact_to_edit = Contact.objects.get(id=cur_id)
        contacts_list = Contact.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'editform.html', {'cur_contact':contact_to_edit, 'contact_list':contacts_list})
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        pass

        

def delete(request, cur_id):
    contact = Contact.objects.get(id=cur_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        contact.delete()
        return redirect('/contacts/list/')

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'contact': contact})
```

editform.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Contacts App
        </title>
        {% load static %}  
            <script src="{% static '/contacts.js'%}"></script>
        {% load static %}
            <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="{% static '/contacts.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Welcome to your contacts management application. You can add contacts, edit them, 
            delete contacts, and see all your contacts.
        </p>
        <div>
            <select id='contact_select'>
                {% for contact in contact_list %}
                    <option value="{{ contact.id }}">
                        {{ contact.id }} {{ contact.firstname }} {{ contact.lastname }}                       
                    </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <button type='button' onclick='editContact()'>Edit Contact</button>
            <button type='button' onclick='deleteContact()'>Delete Contact</button>
            <button type='button' onclick='addContact()'>Add Contact</button>
            <br><br>
            <div>
                <form id='edit_form' action="{% url 'contacts:edit' cur_contact.id %}" method="POST"> 
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <label for='id'>Contact Id</label>
                    <input type='number' name='id' id='id' value="{{cur_contact.id}}" disabled><br>
                    <label for='firstname'>First Name</label>
                    <input type='text' name='first_name' id='first_name' value="{{cur_contact.firstname}}"><br>
                    <label for='lastname'>Last Name</label>
                    <input type='text' name='last_name' id='last_name' value="{{cur_contact.lastname}}"><br>
                    <label for='age'>Age</label>
                    <input type="number" name='age' id='age' value="{{cur_contact.age}}"><br>
                    <label for='phone'>Phone Number</label>
                    <input type='text' name='phone' id='phone' value="{{cur_contact.phone}}"><br>
                    <label for='email'>Email</label>
                    <input type='text' name='email' id='email' value="{{cur_contact.email}}"><br>
                    <label for='gender'>Gender</label>
                    <input type='text' name='gender' id='gender' value="{{cur_contact.gender}}"><br>
                    <input type='submit' id='submit_button' onclick='formValidate()' value="Submit">
                    <button type='button' name='cancel' onclick='homePage()' id='cancel_button'>Cancel</button><br>
                </form>
                <br>
            </div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for contact in contact_list %}
                        <tr>
                            <td> {{ contact.id }} </td>
                            <td> {{ contact.firstname }} </td>
                            <td> {{ contact.lastname }} </td>
                            <td> {{ contact.age }} </td>
                            <td> {{ contact.phone }} </td>
                            <td> {{ contact.email }} </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm pretty new at this so I apologize if I'm missing something or this is a dumb question.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Some things I tried were;

```
def edit(request, cur_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        contact_to_edit = Contact.objects.get(id=cur_id)
        contacts_list = Contact.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'editform.html', {'cur_contact':contact_to_edit, 'contact_list':contacts_list})
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        contact = Contact(
            firstname = request.POST['firstname'],
            lastname = request.POST['lastname'],
            age = request.POST['age'],
            phone = request.POST['phone'],
            email = request.POST['email'],
            gender = request.POST['gender'],
        )
        contact.save()
        return redirect('/contacts/list/')
```

But with this I got this traceback;

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/contacts/edit/6/

Django Version: 3.1.7
Python Version: 3.9.2
Installed Applications:
['contacts.apps.ContactsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Spenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 76, in __getitem__
    list_ = super().__getitem__(key)

During handling of the above exception ('firstname'), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\Spenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Spenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Spenc\Desktop\School\Python CS223\mysite\contacts\views.py", line 34, in edit
    firstname = request.POST['firstname'],
  File "C:\Users\Spenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 78, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /contacts/edit/6/
Exception Value: 'firstname'
```

I also tried to just delete the contact they were attempting to edit so they could re-enter the information.  That however posed a problem with the ID number, and I couldn't get it to delete the contact.

Comment: Show us the methods you have tried and the related error messages including the full traceback.

Comment: I've updated my post with the 2 different things I tried and the traceback that I received for the 1.

Comment: What you are trying to get out of the request is not considered with your form field's name: `last_name` vs. `lastname`.

Comment: I was able to fix that issue, now it's just adding a new contact instead of editing the existing one which is fine if I can get it to also delete the previous one after it's replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an updateview for that Model and specify the fields that you would like to update. You can use a custom form, But trust me these generic views will save you a lot of time .

views.py :

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView


class updimagesUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = updimages
    fields = ['approval']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```

Of all the attributes, you can mention the ones you need to be updated.
As shown in the last line above (template_name_suffix) , use the same naming suffix pattern for the template... [modelname_update_form.html] and display the form...

modelname_update_form.html :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load bootstrap_tags %}
{% block title %} Update {% endblock %}

{% block body%}
<div class="jumbotron">
    Are you sure you want to approve the Image ?
</div>
<br>

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|as_bootstrap  }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

make sure you get the corresponding element you want to update from the template :

```
<h3><a href="{% url 'images:update' pk=val.pk %}">update</a></h3>
```

clicking the above triggers the url. Add the urls ,

**urls.py:**

```
path('update/<int:pk>', views.updimagesUpdateView.as_view() , name = "update"),
```

PS: You can also update values from views using queries to select the desired object and then editing them like this ,

**in views.py :**

```
example = model.objects.filter(id=images.id).update(content=txt)
```

check  out the documentation for more info :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/